# Prove the continuity of $f(x)=x^{2}$ at $x_{0}= 2$ using a specific criteria

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I'd like to know if my proof is correct and if it can be used for showing uniform continuity as well. I don't know the English name of this criteria but if I translate it word by word it's called "sequence-criteria". Let me show you what I did and you will probably know the name of this criteria:

$$f(x_{0}) = 2^{2}=4$$

Now create a sequence whose limit is the point we need to check the continuity at, $2$:

$$a_{x}= 2+\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} 2+\frac{1}{x} =2$$

So far so good, now we take this sequence and put it into the function for each $x$:

$$f(a_{x}) = \left(2+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}$$

Take limit of this and if the limit equals the function value we calculated at the beginning, we did alright and the function is continuous:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(2+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2} =4$$

Thus the function $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}=2$

---

My question, if this was an exam, is everything alright? Is there anything I could have skipped?

Can I use this criteria to prove uniform continuity? How?

Answer (score 2):

This is called the sequential definition of continuity of $f$ at $x$ : whenever a sequence $x_n \to x$, the sequential continuity of $f$ would say that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Let's take an example. Suppose we are trying to prove the continuity of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=2$.

Let us take any sequence $x_n \to 2$. We want to show that $f(x_n) = (x_n)^2 \to 4$.

By definition, for all $ \epsilon> 0$, we need to find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \implies |(x_n)^2 - 4|<\epsilon$.

We would do this as follows: $(x_n)^2-4 = (x_n-2)(x_n+2)$. Because $x_n$ is a convergent sequence so is $x_n+2$, hence it is bounded, say  $x_n+2 < M$ for all $n$. Then, $(x_n)^2-4 < (x_n-2)M$.

Now, because $x_n \to 2$, there exists $N_1  \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_1 \implies |x_n-2| < \frac{\epsilon}M$. But then,
$$
n \geq N_1 \implies |x_n-2| < \frac{\epsilon}M \implies (x_n)^2-4 < (x_n-2)M < \epsilon
$$

Hence, this $N_1$ works, hence $f(x_n) \to 4$. Hence, $f$ is continuous at $x=2$.

Note that it is **not enough** to look at only one sequence converging to $2$, one  must look at *all* sequences converging to $2$ and show that the function value converges to $4$.

A similar argument cannot be used for uniform continuity, because convergence is a *pointwise* property, while uniform continuity  is a *uniform* property , both cannot be checked using a similar procedure. As a general heuristic, functions continuous on a compact set are uniformly continuous.

I hope I was able to communicate, although it may not have been in your language.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2}{1+x} = 0$, not $2$. Similarly, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4}{(1+x)^2} = 0$, not $4$. Hence, your proof is an attempt to show continuity at $0$, not at $2$.

In English it is usually called [**sequential continuity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Sequences_and_nets) and is in the case of $\mathbb{R}$ equivalent to continuity. However, it does not suffice to check only a single sequence for sequential continuity. Let me give you an example:

Suppose we have the function given by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
-10 & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
x^2 & \text{if $x \geq 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
This function is certainly not continuous as it makes a big jump at $0$. However, as your sequence $a_n = \frac{2}{1+n}$ approaches zero from above, you will find that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = 0 = f(0)$. Hence checking only a single sequence is certainly not sufficient to prove continuity.

Comment: Oh yeah I should have better taken $$2+\frac{1}{x}$$ instead..

Answer (score 1):

No, this procedure doesn't prove that the function is continuous at your $x_0$.

It is not enough that you find *some* sequence $x_n$ that converges to $2$ and then prove that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(2)$ for *that particular sequence*. If that was valid we would be able to prove that, for example, Diriclet's function
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x\in\mathbb Q \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
is continuous at $x=2$ because the sequence $2+\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $2$ and $g(2+\frac{1}{n})$ converges to $1$ which also happens to be $g(2)$. But in fact the function is discontinuous at $2$ (and indeed everywhere).

---

The condition that works is that you must prove that *for every possible* sequence $x_n$ that converges to $2$, the sequence of function values $f(x_n)$ will also converge to $f(2)$.

This is not particularly easy to do directly; in fact the most immediate way to do that would be to *start* by proving that $f$ is continuous at $2$ according to the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, and *then* use that property to show that the sequence definition is satisfied.

Comment: How can I prove "that for every possible sequence $x_{n}$? Can you give example please? :D Would this work? "Let $x_{n}$ be a sequence whose limit is $x_{0}$. Then take this sequence and insert it into the function..."?

Comment: @cnmesr: As I said, the easiest method I can imagine is to prove continuity by the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition, and then prove in general that this implies sequential continuity.

Comment: Oh alright I understand now. Thank you everyone :-)